# What does this line of Actionscript do?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm looking at the [as3delaunay library](https://github.com/nodename/as3delaunay) and most of the code is clear to me. This part is not, however (note the line that I put preceded with an arrow):

```
    public function circles():Vector.<Circle>
    {
        var circles:Vector.<Circle> = new Vector.<Circle>();
        for each (var site:Site in _sites)
        {
            var radius:Number = 0;
            var nearestEdge:Edge = site.nearestEdge();

=======>>   !nearestEdge.isPartOfConvexHull() && (radius = nearestEdge.sitesDistance() * 0.5);
            circles.push(new Circle(site.x, site.y, radius));
        }
        return circles;
    }
```

For reference, `isPartOfConvexHull()` is found in `Edge.as` and looks like this:

```
    internal function isPartOfConvexHull():Boolean
    {
        return (_leftVertex == null || _rightVertex == null);
    }
```

What does `!nearestEdge.isPartOfConvexHull()` do? Does that mean that the `radius = nearestEdge.sitesDistance() * 0.5` only executes if `false` is returned from the call to `isPartOfConvexHull()`? Does that stop execution of any other code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is equivalent to:

```
if (!nearestEdge.isPartOfConvexHull()) {
    radius = nearestEdge.sitesDistance() * 0.5;
}
```

---

In the following line:

```
var b:Boolean = expression1 && expression2;
```

`expression2` will not be evaluated if `expression1` is `false` because we already know the final result: `b = false`.

Now in the following line:

```
expression1 && expression2;
```

The same thing happens except the fact that we are not assigning the result to a variable.

And this is exactly what happens in the line you are asking about where `!nearestEdge.isPartOfConvexHull()` is the first expression and `(radius = nearestEdge.sitesDistance() * 0.5)` is the second expression.

Answer (score 2):

To extends @sch answer with some explanations (I didn't knew if editing answer to almost double it was ok).

This is based on lazy execution of the interpreter. If (!nearestEdge.isPartOfConvexHull()) is False then there's no need to execute the second part of the AND statement to know it'll be False, then it's left unexecuted. If it's true the evaluation of the complete statement is needed (and then done) to tell wether or not this boolean is True. So this is equivalent to an if statement.

TMHO this is bad code since it's to much condensed and hard to understand.

Comment: There's a race around improving SO answers ;)

Comment: That's what I thought it did -- but the syntax confused me and I started to doubt my initial impression and wonder if it was somehow changing a parameter value of the Edge. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Yes, it's confusing... When you'll write open source code, don't write stuff like that, it gives you bad karma !